# How to change text color of cell in edit mode in Silverlight DataGrid?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, datagrid

In Silverlight 4 I have a `DataGrid` with a `DataGridTextColumn`. The cells in this column are editable. Now I have the problem that I changed the color of the whole grid to white on black instead of the default black on white. I managed to change all relevant colors, except for the **text color of the cell during edit mode**. This is still black, so it looks pretty bad.

Any hints how to do it? I've now spent plenty of time googling and searching for this problem but found no solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the background of the DataGridCell, the TextBox background in the DataGridTextColumn is transparent, so it should pickup the cell's background.

Here is something that worked for me:

```
<UserControl xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"  
         x:Class="DataGridTextBoxBackground.MainPage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:p="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="p:DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="gridItems" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" />
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Here's the codebehind for the xaml above:

```
    namespace DataGridTextBoxBackground
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<DataItem> items = new List<DataItem>();
            items.Add(new DataItem("item 1"));
            items.Add(new DataItem("item 2"));
            items.Add(new DataItem("item 3"));
            items.Add(new DataItem("item 4"));
            items.Add(new DataItem("item 5"));

            this.gridItems.ItemsSource = items;
        }
    }

    public class DataItem
    {
        public DataItem() { }

        public DataItem(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't work. It does change the cell's foreground color, but in **editing mode**, when the cell's text is not selected, the foreground color is still black.

Comment: You might have some conflicting styles somewhere.  Are you using a theme or are you styling everything yourself - if so how?